# How Do I Use More Than One Style On HTML Label?

Tags: html, gsp

The following HTML code works on my GSP to make the label **bold**, but I'd also like to assign a bottom-margin.

Here is the current code for my label:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="font-weight: bold;" for="customerSection">
                    Most Updated Customer Information Available
</label>
```

I would also like to set the following style on this label:

```
style="margin-bottom: 0.3cm"
```

However I have not needed to assign both to a single label yet. How would I go about assigning both the bold style and the margin-bottom style to this label?

Comment: Why not use the `control-label` class and style with CSS (or some other selector)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ; symbol in CSS (the programming language by which styles are written in) means an end of a statement. Meaning; to change multiple styles you must simply separate them by this symbol.

Amended HTML :

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em;" for="customerSection">
                    Most Updated Customer Information Available
</label>
```

For sizing, use em, px, or %.

An additional way of doing bold is also to surround the text in tags, instead - such as :

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1em;" for="customerSection">
                        <strong>Most Updated Customer Information Available</strong>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add all the css like below, as inline css is not a good practice. I suggest you to give all the styles like below, in different file or same file inside "style" tag

```css
label.control-label.col-sm-6 {
  margin-bottom: 0.3cm;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="customerSection">
                    Most Updated Customer Information Available
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="font-weight: bold;margin-bottom: 0.3cm" for="customerSection">
                Most Updated Customer Information Available </label>
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from some explanatory text. In this case you could discuss why it works and if there are any limitations, and maybe even suggest that there is a better way to handle styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more css syntax after semicolon

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="font-weight: bold;margin-bottom: 0.3cm;" for="customerSection">
                    Most Updated Customer Information Available
</label>
```